# Create a catch/replace error counterpart that does not complete the publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm struggling with handling errors in Combine and find it very counter-intuitive that [catching](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/catch(_:)) or [replacing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/replaceerror(with:)) an error completes and ends the publisher. For example, this ends the publisher even though I handled the exception:

```
Just([1, 2, 3, NaN, 5, 6])
   .tryMap { _ in throw DummyError() }
   .catch { _ in Just(4) } // or .replaceError(with: 4)
   .sink { print($0) } // <-- ends at 4 and ignores 5, 6, and anything ever again
```

If the publisher was subscribed to some system change, the first error will make my app dead until the user restarts the app. I would like to create a `catch` counterpart that does NOT end the publisher. I know `flatMap` is used for that, but that creates a whole other dimension of complexity such as inverting inner/outer publishers, publishers getting duplicated infinitely, back pressure, etc.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
Just([1, 2, 3, NaN, 5, 6])
   .tryMap { _ in throw DummyError() }
   .ignoreError { error in
        log("Error occurred: \(error)")
   }
   .sink { print($0) } // 1, 2, 3, 5, 6
```

How can I encapsulate this intent in a simple custom chain command called `ignoreError` and make my publishers live on?

Comment: What about `.replaceError` instead of `.catch`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `.replaceError` also completes and ends the publisher: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/replaceerror(with:). But also I do not want to emit a default value, but just log and do not emit anything.

Comment: You need to use flatMap for this, sorry. I don't think it incurs as much complexity as you seem to think it does though, but that's subjective.

Comment: Can you pls add an example in an answer so I can understand more? You're probably right and I need to overcome a mental hurdle

Comment: @TruMan1, generate a possibly-failing publisher inside a `flatMap` and `replaceError` there.  `flatMap` will shield the pipeline. https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-continual-error-handling

Comment: I'm hoping to encapsulate this in `ignoreError` because it's sounding like I have to create a dummy publisher on top and move my original publisher in the `flatMap`. That's what I don't get what is this dummy publisher and seems like a hack to create a dummy publisher that is just used to kickstart the publisher?

Comment: @TruMan1, as I've shown in my answer, you don't need an outer dummy publisher, but you need an inner publisher emitted for each upstream value that could result in a failure. There's another paradigm like that of a `retry` - but it re-subscribes to a failed upstream, which isn't quite what would work for your example.

Comment: Thx for the example, it does shed light. I've been trying to digest it and map it to other use cases, but what if the upstream publisher does emit errors and no way around it, such as file disk observer or some catch-all subject? That case I'm not sure if there's a way around having to create the dummy publisher on top. Retry and re-subscribe sounds interesting but you're right maybe doesn't translate well for normal cases, looking into these..

Comment: Oh `retry` sounds good! I think it's fair to put a limit on a failing publisher even if it's 10 times. Still not sure how I would recover the app if the retries is exhausted instead of kick them out of the screen and let them start over. Also, seems like with `retry` I wouldn't use `catch` to passively handle the error, but `handleEvents(receiveCompletion:)`.

Comment: @TruMan1, here's a way to think about publishers that fail: a publisher's job is to emit values and that's what you subscribe for; and it does that, until it fails - i.e. the entire publisher fails. You either need to resubscribe - basically start afresh, which works well for transient network errors, or you need to isolate the failing publisher like I showed with `flatmap`.

Comment: Thank you for the gems. I'm starting to grasp the paradigm shift and will work down the path of a better recovery flow, such as resubscribing after failures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An error completing the pipeline is part of the contract by which publishers and subscribers work. And this makes sense. If an upstream publisher throws an error and doesn't know how to recover on its own, it's basically done. It's not unlike a function throwing an error.

In your example, `tryMap` throws an error, and although a downstream like `replaceError` can transform the error for its downstream, it does not expect any more values from its upstream, so it too completes.

`flatMap` shields the rest of the pipeline from the error-throwing publisher. In other words, the upstream of `flatMap` doesn't throw an error, and `flatMap` itself doesn't throw an error since the returned inner publisher (the pipeline with `Just`/`tryMap`/`catch`) handles the error.

```
Just([1, 2, 3, 5, 6])
   .flatMap {
      Just($0)
        .tryMap { _ in throw DummyError() }
        .catch { _ in Just(4) } 
   }
   .sink { print($0) }
```